# Two UpdatePanels in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two updatepanels and inside these updatepanels are two modalpopups.  I'm trying to change the label inside one of the updatepanel from a control(button) inside the first updatepanel inside a modalpopup.  Once the button is clicked, the first modalpopup will close and the second modalpopup will show with the label changed however the label inside the popup does not show up.

When I try calling the secondUpdatePanel.Update() in the code behind, the second modal popup does not even show up.  Help is appreciated!  I've seen the tutorials for assigning asyncpostbacktriggers from the first pop-up to the second popup those tutorials aren't inside modal popups.

So, I might be missing something.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlFormalAppeal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFormalAppeal" runat="server" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpopupFormalAppeal" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="hfFormalAppeal" 
                PopupControlID="pnlFormalAppealPopup" 
                CancelControlID="btnClose" 
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
                <Animations>
                    <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
                    <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration="0.75" /></OnHiding>
                </Animations>
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
            <!-- Details View for Formal Appeal -->
            <asp:DetailsView ID="dvFormalAppeal" runat="server" Height="50px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CssClass="dvCSS" >
                <!-- DATA HERE -->
            </asp:DetailsView>
            <div class="footer">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                    CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                    &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbeSubmit" runat="server" 
                    ConfirmText="Submit Appointment Request?" TargetControlID="btnSubmit">
                </asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Second UpdatePanel inside a modalpopup.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="panelConfirmation" >
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlMessageBox" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSubmissionConfirmationBox" runat="server" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpopupConfirmation" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="hfSubmissionConfirmationBox" 
                PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                CancelControlID="btnClose" 
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <div class="mpopupBody">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmationMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmClose" runat="server" Text="Close" 
                            CausesValidation="false" onclick="btnConfirmClose_Click" />
                    </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnConfirmClose" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mpopupFormalAppeal.Hide();

        this.lblConfirmationMessage.Text = "Text changed!";
        //this.upPnlMessageBox.Update();
        this.mpopupConfirmation.Show();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same scenario... I managed to solve it by re-ordering my layout design.

I placed the modalpopup outside of the UpdatePanel like below:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSubmissionConfirmationBox" runat="server" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpopupConfirmation" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="hfSubmissionConfirmationBox" 
    PopupControlID="Panel1" 
    CancelControlID="btnClose" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="panelConfirmation" >
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlMessageBox" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="mpopupBody">
                <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmationMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmClose" runat="server" Text="Close" 
                    CausesValidation="false" onclick="btnConfirmClose_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnConfirmClose" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```